# CakePHP: How to create a routing "fall-back"

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

Our URL structure has been evolving quickly and our logs sometimes fill up with 404 errors from users trying to reach old, non-existent URLs. I'd like to keep the logs clean, and also avoid showing those users a 404 page. Is there way to set a "fallback" route so that if, say, the action isn't found the user lands on the controller's index (or anywhere besides an error page).

I know how to manually connect routes conditionally. This is how we've been managing this issue so far, but it's labor-intensive because we need to add a new one every time the URL structure changes.

Ex:

```
Router::connect('/old/url/:param', array('controller' => 'new', 'action' => 'index'), array('param' => '.*[^0-9/]+.*'));
```

It would be a lot easier if we could do something like this:

```
Router::connect('/some_controller/ + ...anything that doesnt exist', array('controller' => 'some_controller', 'action' => 'index') );
```

Is this possible?

**Update**

To clarify, the reason I'm not simply using a wildcard is this: the URLs I need to connect/redirect don't all follow the same pattern. To demonstrate, here are some URLs I'm trying to redirect...

```
example.com/a/b/ --> example.com/a/
example.com/a/b/34  --> example.com/a/
example.com/a/c/ --> example.com/a/
```

But I DON'T want to redirect this...

```
example.com/a/d
```

So my problem is not solved by what Burzum suggested below (translated to this example): `Router::redirect('/a/b/*' ...` or `Router::redirect('/a/*' ...` because this would either miss links that should be targeted or target links that should (respectively).

Of course, I could just write new connect/redirect routes for each and every link I want to target, but avoiding this hassle is the point of this question. Also, it's an entirely "reactive" solution in that I need to apply new routes after checking the debug logs and seeing requests to non-existent controllers/actions/. I'm trying to be pro-active and *prevent* my logs filling up with bad requests when something changes.

Answer (score 0):

[See the book for redirect routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing). I'm not going to copy and paste the whole section for you so I recommend you to read the link.

Based on your comment I assume you don't understand the answer or you have other requirements. Your questions states the following:

> Our URL structure has been evolving quickly and our logs sometimes
>   fill up with 404 errors from users trying to reach old, non-existent
>   URLs

The proper solution to this is to use a redirect and HTTP status 301. The following section is taken from the official documentation and the example modified to help you understanding it.

> Redirect routing allows you to issue HTTP status 30x redirects for
>   incoming routes, and point them at different URLs. This is useful when
>   you want to inform client applications that a resource has moved and
>   you don’t want to expose two URLs for the same content.

```
Router::redirect('/old/url/*', array('controller' => 'some', 'action' => 'index'), array('status' => 301));
```

[Read about HTTP statuses, mostly 301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
>   permanent redirection, meaning current links or records using the URL
>   that the 301 Moved Permanently response is received for should be
>   updated to the new URL provided in the Location field of the response.
>   This status code should be used with the location header. RFC 2616
>   states that:

- If a client has link-editing capabilities, it should update all references to the Request URI.
- The response is cachable.
- Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity should contain a small hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).
- If the 301 status code is received in response to a request of any type other than GET or HEAD, the client must ask the user before redirecting.

**Update:**

> Also, it's an entirely "reactive" solution in that I need to apply new
>   routes after checking the debug logs and seeing requests to
>   non-existent controllers/actions/.

Well, that should be a finite amount of actions. So you would have to declare them all, at least for each controller and make sure it matches a set of actions:

```
Router::redirect('/a/:action/*', array('controller' => 'some', 'action' => 'index'), array('status' => 301, 'action' => 'action1|action2'));
```

If you have more specific URLs you want to match you'll have to find a pattern that can be matched or you have to declare each route / redirect.

> example.com/a/b/34

This looks more like a specific record not being found any more. You should have a method that tries to get the data, throw a NotFoundException in your (hopefully) model method and catch it in the controller and use $this->redirect(array(...), 301); to redirect them.

Another reason why you should use the 301 status for a redirect over a route is SEO: If you just  connect the same content to several URLs you'll get very likely a negative effect of this from most search engines.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I already know how to redirect/connect routes. I'm not going to copy and paste my whole question again so I recommend you reread the question.

Comment: My answer is the proper answer for "trying to reach old, non-existent URLs!" because in this case you should do a redirect with status 301 (Moved Permanently). For the other part simply use a wildcard /some_controller/*. See the routing documentation.

Comment: I've read your question twice and I recommend *you* to read my answer as well twice. It is definitely the proper solution to your problem. Just use a wildcard within the redirect route... Let me spoon feed you.

Comment: I cannot use the wildcard as you've shown. Have a look at my update above for explanation.

Comment: I did. There's a lot of helpful information there, but it sounds like the bottom line is there is no way to set a default route/redirect that applies when an action doesn't exist. In other words, there's nothing I can do to prevent non-existent actions from seeing a 404 page unless I manually specify each one. Right?

Comment: The router can't know the action does not exist. You could write a custom route class and do a check for each URL but this basically causes you at least one additional query per request and route that is checked using this route class. Lots of overhead. I honestly think your issue is not a real issue. Just remove the 404s from your log if they disturb you. For all other cases my answer provides the solutions I think. You could as well implement a catch all for the NotFoundException and do a redirect to / in the case its thrown.

Comment: I think the last sentence from your comment is exactly what I'm looking for. I agree that I may be barking up the wrong tree by considering this in the context of routes... where is the correct place to catch() NotFoundExceptions?

Comment: Guess you'll have to write a custom error handler. Check the book for how to do it.